# JMeter recording without GUI

Tags: user-interface, proxy, jmeter, recording, command-line-interface

I'm currently trying to use Apache JMeter to record HTTP-Traffic for later playback.
JMeter supports both recording an non-GUI-Mode to run Traffic/Tests, there even is a built in remote-control-mode to use a single GUI-Client with multiple jmeter-servers.

The JMeter-Proxy has to run on an ubuntu-Server in our case, so i can't use the default-mode with GUI (well technically i could, by using X-Forwarding, but thats a pretty uggly hack and i would lose any possibility of scripting against that)

The RC-Mode where the local GUI controlls the jmeter-server on my Server-Machine works pretty well, but the Module "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" is run on the Machine running the GUI, so i can't use that either.

The non-gui-mode of jmeter on the other hand lists a bunch of options one could supply on command line (jmeter -n and jmeter -h gives a list and short explanations). Recording traffic isn't mentioned there at all.

I would like to know if and how it's possible to use JMeter this way (recording traffic without GUI) or if X-Forwarding is really the only chance left.

Comment: What is it you're trying to record? Are the requests coming from a browser or something else? Never mind, I see in your comments below you need to be able to record non browser traffic.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, of course, you can do it with plugin for Chrome browser - [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](http://blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeters-chrome-extension-record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter). It allows you to record JMeter script without running JMeter

Comment: this doesn't work for multiple reasons... 

a) Blazemeter integrates into the JMeter-GUI, so we keep the same Problem

b) Blazemeter doesn't keep the recorded Data on our Server

c) Blazemeter isn't a proxy, we can't restrict use to Chrome (ord $other_browser), but we need to record wget-requests and the likes too