# Recording traffic using JMeter without using GUI

Tags: jmeter, network-traffic

I want to record HTTPS using JMeter, but I want not to use JMeter GUI, only using command line/background service

I found [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072507/jmeter-recording-without-gui) but without relevant/accepted/upvoted answer

I want to use JMeter recording as a background service, is it possible? if not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you trust only to accepted answers then you might be surprised a little bit when you see the [number of upvotes on not accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ano%20score%3A%3E10%20wiki%3Ano%20is%3Aanswer) like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6866485/2897748). Given the answer hasn't been flagged/removed there is a chance it's valid and my expectation is that you should try it and upvote if it works and downvote in the opposite case.
2. If you tried the answer already but it doesn't fit your needs here is another one: any command-line [network sniffer tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) should be able of capturing the traffic and filtering it to SSL/TLS, for example [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/). Once you get .har or .pcap file with the traffic you can either use [online [.har][5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format))/[.pcap][6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap)/etc. converter to JMeter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/) or just paste captured request(s) payload(s) into the [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it/) sampler.